# Count maximum number of records using wildcard in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to count how many records are there which starts with 'fl' and ends with 'sqft' in mysql database. The records are

```
post_id     meta_key
1           fl_0_sqft
1           fl_1_sqft
1           _fl_0_sqft
1           _fl_1_sqft
2           fl_0_sqft
2           _fl_0_sqft
3           fl_0_sqft
3           fl_1_sqft
3           fl_2_sqft
3           _fl_0_sqft
3           _fl_1_sqft
3           _fl_2_sqft
```

I want the result set to be

```
ID      Count
1       2
2       1
3       3
```

My query is

```
SELECT 
    wp_postmeta.post_id as ID, COUNT(*)
FROM
    wp_postmeta
WHERE
    wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%fl'
GROUP BY wp_postmeta.post_id
```

The above query returns 0 record.

Is there anything like '%fl_*_sqft%' I can use after LIKE.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` mean anything, you should try with

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76982/1)**

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'fl%sqft'
```